# Hide repositories from menu on a project on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to hide two repositories (App 1 and 2 below) from the menu on a project on Azure DevOps.

Select a project -> Repos -> below

[image]

The reason is that App 1 and 2 have code, but are not being used at the moment. So we will show them in the future. Thus, we want the ability to show/hide them.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can go in your azure devops setting to edit your repository settings.

In this page you can manage all security options and allow specific user to work with your branches.

Some documentation from Microsoft website :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: I tried that, but I cannot see a turn on/off option.

Comment: Best way for me is to create a new groupin Teams with only available people for this projects. And you will manage to have only this group that can access to the repos. more about security in branches and repo : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=vsts

Comment: this link is for branches, not repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can disable the repository. This will keep listing your disabled repositories but no one can access them. Instead, the repository page just warns about its disabled status (see the picture below).

See [this article](https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-disable-a-repository-in-azure-devops/) that brings more detail and is the source of the images below.

[image: Example: displaying a disabled repository]

[image: Example of how to disable a repository in Azure DevOps]